# Twitter API NameError Python Social Media Analytics

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to build a search app using python. I have removed my key.

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import json
from urllib.parse import urlparse

#Endpoints
url_rest = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
url_streaming = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json"

#Define parameters
params = {
 app_key:'myPersonalKey',
 app_secret:'myPersonalKey',
 oauth_token:'myPersonalKey',
 oauth_token_secret:'myPersonalKey'
}

auth = OAuth1(
    auth_params['myPersonalKey'], 
    auth_params['myPersonalKey'], 
    auth_params['myPersonalKey'], 
    auth_params['myPersonalKey']
)

q = '@marchmadness'

params = {'q' : q, 'count' : 100, 'lang' : 'en'}

results = requests.get(url_rest,params=params, auth=auth)

for tweet in results.json()['statuses']:
    print (tweet['text'])

stream_results = requests.get(url_streaming, stream=True,auth=auth)

for line in stream_results.iter_lines():
    try:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print(json.loads(decoded_line)['text'])
    except:
         pass
```

Here is the error I am getting:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     10 #Define parameters
     11 params = {
---> 12  app_key:'',
     13  app_secret:'',
     14  oauth_token:'',

NameError: name 'app_key' is not defined

This is from the Book "Python Social Media Analytics

Comment: You need to wrap the keys in your `params` dictionary with quotes so they are strings

Comment: I tried that but it do not work.

Comment: params = {
'app_key':'YOUR_APP_KEY',
'app_secret':'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
'oauth_token':'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN',
'oauth_token_secret':'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
}

auth = OAuth1(
    auth_params['app_key'], 
    auth_params['app_secret'], 
    auth_params['oauth_token'], 
    auth_params['oauth_token_secret']
)

Comment: now the issue is NameError: name 'auth_params' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Change the "params" dictionary name to "auth_params":

```
auth_params = {
 app_key:'myPersonalKey',
 app_secret:'myPersonalKey',
 oauth_token:'myPersonalKey',
 oauth_token_secret:'myPersonalKey'
}
```